# Thread 1 : SIGBRT

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I'm working on a iOS app and it was working totally fine. All of a sudden, my app now crashes on the iOS Simulator and I get highlighted code on main.m.

This is the highlighted code :

> return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));

The errors I'm getting is :

> *argv  char *  "/Users/AMITNKALRA/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7528F103-5C95-4539-BA37-B703F26BF564/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/61E964E2-F001-44A6-BB9F-90E158CC41CF/Amit Kalra.app/Amit Kalra"  0x00007fff5148a538
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
> (lldb)

I don't know what to do? I've tried everything I could have possibly done. I have now decided to ask for help. Hopefully, someone can help me!

Comment: It would be great if you provide console crash log. Just a guess, mostly this crash happens due to unknown IBOutlets/IBActions, do have a check with your storyboard, if any has exclamation symbol in file owner connections, remove those.

Comment: See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had changed my ViewController name in Xcode but the actual file name hadn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

It could be probably your Xcode is corrupted or some file have got deleted from the Xcode installer. Please reinstall your Xcode and check if your project runs properly.

Comment: Hey, I tried re-installing Xcode and I'm still occurring with this same error.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that your app didn't crash on that line.  Have a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html to see how to set an exception breakpoint which will help you to get more relevant information.